# MariaDB InnoDB does not reuse blob storage and file keeps getting bigger. Why?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, blob

I have two tables in my MariaDB (10.4.12) which store images (JPEG). They are `mediumblob`s, typically around 1MB each (though it varies). When a new image first arrives, it gets placed in the `TempImages` table where it stays for... less than a minute. Usually 10-20 seconds. Then it gets moved to `FinalImages` table where it is kept until the end of time.

The images come in fairly rarely - one every few minutes or so - so the `TempImages` table is actually empty most of the time. As it currently stands, the absolutely very worst it could have is maybe 20 images at the same time, and that's already pushing it.

However for some reason this table continues to grow. Yesterday it had reached over 30GB in size, so we dropped and recreated it because disk space was getting scarce. But today it's already reached 150MB.

The engine is InnoDB (there are transactions involved when inserting/deleting in the table) and `innodb_file_per_table=ON`.

**Why doesn't InnoDB reuse the empty space in the table but just keeps increasing file size?**

Here's the full create script, maybe there are some extra important details there:

```
CREATE TABLE `TempImages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  `small_image` mediumblob DEFAULT NULL,
  `mime_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DATA` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `TempData` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

(Note: this is not the same as [not releasing disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table). I expect the disk space to remain allocated to the table, but I also expect the new rows to reuse the space that was left over by deleted rows, as explained in the linked question. For some reason this isn't happening.)

(Preemptive note: Fragmentation also shouldn't be an issue since the table is literally empty most of the time)

Comment: Does it help if you run the `OPTIMIZE TABLE tempimages` statement?

Comment: @SalmanA - Yes, that reduced the size, although only because it resulted in a drop+recreate. Do I really need to schedule this to be executed every night? It's a solution, sure, but why is it even needed in the first place? Shouldn't InnoDB be smart enough to reuse empty pages?

Comment: For your use case, I guess a memory engine or MyISAM engine would fit better than innoDB.

Comment: @Tensibai - could you elaborate, please? I kinda like my transactions, but, of course, can work around that if I really need to. In meta you also said something about `inherent to how innodb works to keep history until you tell you really don't care anymore about history with OPTIMIZE`. I haven't heard of this at all. What is this history and how can one access it?

Comment: @Vilx- About the InnoDB transaction log (which is what consume disk space in fact): https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/02/03/how-innodb-handles-redo-logging/#:~:text=The%20InnoDB%20transaction%20log%20handles,the%20pages%20inside%20the%20database. And indeed using memory or MyISAM as engine means forgetting about transactions on this table, but as it's a temp storage that shouldn't be a hard drawback, choice between memory and myisam is about data loss in case of cirtical failure. The various engines definition are detailed here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered on https://www.reddit.com/r/mariadb/, but for the record here as well, the solution is to update to a more recent version of MariaDB, as this was fixed in https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23072